# How to nest a "for i in range()" loop in another loop that takes data from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

The following code runs 599 instances of bootstrapping using data stored in the dictionary `data_rois`. `data_rois` is a dictionary that includes many keys and each key is associated with an array of numeric values. This part of the code works fine when it is coded as below:

```
boot_i = []
for i in range(599):
    boot = np.random.choice(data_rois["interoception"], size=N)
    boot = np.mean(boot)
    boot_i.append(boot)
```

Now, I would like to apply bootstrapping for many keys in the dictionary `data_rois`. Therefore, I apply a for loop as below that aims to store the bootstrapping results in another dictionary called `boot_rois = {}`. The code shown below aims to shorten the code above, since the code above would get really long if I had to repeat it many times for all keys in `data_rois`.

```
rois = ["interoception", "extero", ...] # A long list of rois
boot_rois = {}
for roi in rois:
    for i in range(599):
        boot = np.random.choice(data_rois[roi], size=N)
        boot = np.mean(boot)
        boot_rois[roi] = roi
```

**The problem:** The code works. However, my code appears to ignore `for i in range(599)` but only runs `boot = np.random.choice(data_rois[roi], size=N)` one time instead of 599 times. What line of code is missing in the nested for loop so that it runs bootstrapping 599 times instead of 1 time?

**Update:**
I specify my aim here. My aim is to compute the standard deviation (SD) for each roi, based on the 599 bootstraps.

Here is an updated code suggested by someone in this topic. I changed that code to compute the SD and the results look fine.

```
boot_rois = {}
for roi in rois:
    last_boot = None
    for i in range(599):
        boot = np.random.choice(data_rois[roi], size=N)
        boot = np.std(boot)
        if(last_boot is not None):
          boot = np.std([boot,last_boot])
        
        boot_rois[roi] = boot
        last_boot = boot_rois[roi]
```

Comment: if you iterate rois why do you want to iterate from 0 to 599? isn't 599 the number of rois you have? or each roi must be iterated 599 times?

Comment: 599 is not meant to be the number of the rois, but the number of bootstraps I would like to apply for np.random.choice. Yes, each roi has to be iterated 599 times.

Comment: What's the value of `N`?

Comment: @Philipp you do not seem to be using `i` inside that inner loop, is this intended? How do you know it doesn't actually iterate 599 times?

Comment: N = 23. N is the number of subjects from the data that I use, irrespective of the 599 range loop. Rafalon, you are right. What would be the correct way to use i in the inner loop so that np.random.choice really runs 599 times? I can change the range to 1, 50, or 599, it does not change the results. Hence it appears that it is not used.

Comment: I think it actually runs 599 times, but you seem to overwrite `boot` everytime, so you only keep the last result... If you want to be sure, just try to add a `print(i)` on the first line of your inner loop, and you'll see that it really loops 599 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using comprehension list instead of nested loops:

```py
rois = ["interoception", "extero", ...] # A long list of rois
boot_rois = {}
for roi in rois:
    # will execute np.random.choice 599 times and store these results in a list
    rand_choices = [np.mean(np.random.choice(data_rois[roi], size=N)) for _ in range(599)]
    # will calculate the standard deviation of those 599 results
    boot_rois[roi] = np.std(rand_choices)
```

This will run `np.random.choice` 599 times and store these results in a list (I added `np.mean(...)` so you can calculate the stdev on those 599 mean values), so you can run `np.std` on that list, and store this final result in `boot_rois[roi]`

---

Below is runnable code I used for tests purpose. It generates 20 random numbers between 0 and 50, and calculates the stdev:

```py
import random
import numpy as np

rand_ints = [random.randint(0, 50) for _ in range(20)]
print(rand_ints)
stdev = np.std(rand_ints)
print(stdev)
```

First execution:

> ```
> [9, 44, 13, 0, 43, 12, 4, 40, 35, 38, 43, 0, 3, 38, 39, 45, 37, 14, 4, 21]
> 16.908281994336384
> ```

Second execution:

> ```
> [2, 20, 17, 32, 0, 39, 23, 27, 24, 41, 8, 21, 2, 7, 21, 3, 27, 7, 15, 36]
> 12.531560158256433
> ```

---

In order to emulate calculating the stdev of means of samples, I tried this:

```py
import random
import numpy as np

rand_ints = [np.mean([random.randint(0, 50) for _ in range(10)]) for _ in range(20)]
print(rand_ints)
stdev = np.std(rand_ints)
print(stdev)
```

Which gave me:

> ```
> [25.8, 16.9, 27.6, 21.8, 20.6, 30.5, 19.4, 32.9, 27.8, 18.5, 24.5, 18.7, 23.1, 26.9, 30.6, 25.1, 24.9, 26.5, 21.8, 25.8]
> 4.2607833786758045
> ```

Comment: One question. Don't I have to add ```.mean()``` to ```rand_choices = [np.random.choice(data_rois[roi], size=N).mean() for _ in range(599)]```? As far as I know, even when I am interested in the standard deviation, I first have to take teh mean of the bootstrapped sample, and subsequently compute the SD of it. Sorry, I just realized this is not related to your code. Anyway, thank you, your code works fine too and is very easy to understand!

Comment: Well as I have no idea about what `np.random.choice(data_rois[roi], size=N)` returns, I can't answer for sure, but if it returns a list and you want to calculate the standard deviation of these 599 means, sure, you should add that `.mean()`. If it returns a single value (like in my `random` example), then no, it isn't needed

Comment: Re-reading your code, it should probably be `np.mean(np.random.choice(...))` (don't know if `np.random.choice(...).mean()` will work). I will edit my answer to reflect this

Comment: Once again thanks for your help. One note that is maybe interesting for you too. ```[np.mean(np.random.choice(data_rois[roi], size=N)) for _ in range(599)]``` is not the same as ```[np.random.choice(data_rois[roi], size=N).mean() for _ in range(599)]```. The first code takes the mean of the whole line, hence giving one single output. Conversely, the second line takes the mean of ```np.random.choice(data_rois[roi], size=N)```and then gives 599 outputs (which is what I needed). I did not provide the complete code since it is long and messy, and I thought it just makes everything too complicated.

Comment: @Philipp did you really try both? I think you might have written `np.mean([np.random.choice(data_rois[roi], size=N) for _ in range(599)])` instead

Comment: Oh, you are right. Sorry, my mind is a mess after spending hours on this...

Answer (score 2):

It is partially unclear what you are trying to do since you didn't provide a minimal reproducible example. I've filled in as best I can and I think this should still help you solve your problem. You may need to adjust the type of aggregation to fit your needs.

Your for loop is of course executing as many times as it says it is.
I believe you forgot to set the value of boot_rois to boot, otherwise your code just regenerates the ROI list.

```
        boot_rois[roi] = boot
```

A secondary problem with your code is that everytime you do your inner for loop, you are just overwriting the same key in your dictionary. You probably want to do something like this instead. It isn't completely clear what type of math you are trying to do, but assuming you want to calculate the average between your 599 random arrays in a rolling fashion you could do this:

```
import numpy as np
N=10
data_rois={"interoception" : [1,2], "extero"  : [2,3] }
rois = data_rois.keys() # A long list of rois
boot_rois = {}
for roi in rois:
    last_boot = None
    for i in range(7):
        boot = np.random.choice(data_rois[roi], size=N)
        print(boot)
        boot = np.mean(boot)
        # During first iteration aggregator last_boot is None
        if(last_boot is not None):
          # Average with the last iteration and repeat
          # This logic may need to be replaced with whatever math you are trying to do
          boot = np.mean([boot,last_boot])
        
        boot_rois[roi] = boot
        last_boot = boot_rois[roi]
        
print(boot_rois)
```

Note: Doing it this way means that the average is not the average of each of the 7, if you want to do that you can store them in a sum variable and divide by the number of iterations you performed in the inner for loop. Mathematically, doing the mean multiple times is different than summing everything and dividing by the number of sums. Make sure your math is correct.

Comment: Thank you. I am interested in the standard deviation of each roi. Based on the 599 bootstraps, I would like to compute each ROIs standard deviation. I took your code, changed it to np.std, and the results look reasonable. I will edit my code in the initial post to show you what I did.

Comment: if you want to calculate the standard deviation of each boot produced inside of the inner for loop you probably want to make last_boot a list and update last_boot[i] with each value so that you can calculate it correctly. What you are doing in your update doesn't seem correct mathwise to me because your essentially running stdev(1,stdev(2,stdev(3,...))) which is not going to be the standard deviation of all 599 bootstraps. instead, store the whole list and run np.std on that